# After return value, in main func the value was changed

Tags: python

I tried write function that use with subscription.
when i print value i get my expectation, but when i returned value i get some thing else.
I add link with my output.
when I print in function I get my expectation after return to main script i get other value.

The out put is:

```
/cad/workSpaces/EDISON_cadm/.cad
poooo
f-----  1       - - - ./.cad/runsets/pvs/t.00_00_01_scr/RCE_TS18SL_QRC_3M1T3_USG/EAD/1/setup/TSL_0.18_3M1T3_USG_setup.ini
None
```

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import os
import sys
import subprocess
import soscmd
import re

if __name__== '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) < 1:
            print ("Usage: '%s <Object Name> '" %sys.argv[0])
            sys.exit(1)
    objName = sys.argv[1]

    class Terminal:
        def __init__(self, command=None):
            print ("poooo")
            self.command = None
            self.stderr = subprocess.STDOUT
            self.stdout = subprocess.PIPE
            if command is not None and command !='':
                self.command = command

        def run(self, command=None):
            if command is not None and command !='':
                self.command = command
            if self.command is not None:
                cmd_elems =  self.command.split()
                sub_proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd_elems, stderr=self.stderr, stdout=self.stdout)
                output, error = sub_proc.communicate()
                aaa = output.decode("utf-8").splitlines()
                print(aaa[0])
                #sub_proc.kill()
                return aaa[0]       
            #return None

    def pysos(cmd):
        term = Terminal()
        term.run('soscmd ' + cmd)
    print (objName)
    if os.path.isdir(objName):
        result = pysos('status -sall /cad/workSpaces/EDISON_cadm/.cad')
        print (result)
        i = 0
            #while i < len(result):
                #   print (result)
                    #print (listObject[i])
                #   i += 1
    else:
        print ("ovedddd")
```

Comment: you forgot `return` in `pysos()` - `return term.run('soscmd ' + cmd)`